# WPF XML Bind to RelativeSource PreviousSibling?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have an XMLDataProvider and I need to bind a property to a property of a previous sibling item. Here is an XAML example:

```
<ListBoxItem status="{Binding RelativeSource={Relativesource PreviousSibling}, path=somevalue" />
```

Is it possible to access properties from sibling items using Binding only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using RelativeSource mode with **PreviousData**:

```
<ListBoxItem Status="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}, 
             Path=somevalue" />
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode.aspx):

[image]